# Constrained model demonstrates slightly better fit than the unconstrained model (Measurment invariance). Explanation?

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I am currently examining measurement invariance in lavaan. I create my unconstrained model. Then I apply constrains to loadings and loadings+intercepts. I use the WLSMV estimator. The following pattern in the results is replicated with the DWLS estimator without mean and variance adjusted. (ordered=TRUE argument in one case and estimator="DWLS" in another)

```
# Unconstrained model

m1<-'
       S=~S1+S2+S3+S4+S5+S6
       P=~P1+P2+P3+P4+P5+P6
       C=~C1+C2+C3+C4+C5+C6
                                        
       '

m1.fit<-cfa(m1,data=Phase2,estimator="WLSMV", 
                                   group="Gender", meanstructure=TRUE, std.lv=TRUE)

summary(m1.fit,fit.measures=TRUE,standardized=TRUE)


# Constrained model (Metric)

m2<-'
       S=~S1+S2+S3+S4+S5+S6
       P=~P1+P2+P3+P4+P5+P6
       C=~C1+C2+C3+C4+C5+C6
                                        
       '

m2.fit<-cfa(m2,data=Phase2,estimator="WLSMV", 
                                        group="Gender", group.equal=c("loadings"), 
                                        meanstructure=TRUE, std.lv=TRUE)

summary(m2.fit,fit.measures=TRUE,standardized=TRUE)

# Constrained model (Scalar)

m3<-'
       S=~S1+S2+S3+S4+S5+S6
       P=~P1+P2+P3+P4+P5+P6
       C=~C1+C2+C3+C4+C5+C6
                                        
      '

m3.fit<-cfa(m3,data=Phase2,estimator="WLSMV", 
                                        group="Gender", group.equal=c("loadings","intercepts"), 
                                        meanstructure=TRUE, std.lv=TRUE)

summary(m3.fit,fit.measures=TRUE,standardized=TRUE)

# Compare MI models

ComMI=compareFit(m1.fit,m2.fit,m3.fit)


summary(ComMI)
```

Unscaled chi-square test statistics follow a logical pattern with m1 having the lowest and m3 the highest. (m1 = 181.64, m2 = 239.28, m3 = 259.97)

Scaled chi-square test statistics on the other hand show that the loading-constrained model (m2) has better fit. (m1 = 394.881, m2 = 380.839†, m3 = 408.288).

The same pattern is followed by scaled fit indices. CFI for example is: m1 = .954, m2 = .965†, m3 = .960.). Scaled RMSEA follows the same pattern. Scaled SRMR is the only one that demonstrates best fit for the unconstrained model.

Unscalled fit indices are not helpful because they show perfect fit and are the same for all models.

What is a plausible explanation for this? I thought that by definition constrained models should evidence worse fit.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Hello Nikos, perhaps your question belongs to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lavaan)?

Comment: uuuuuu, thank you. I'll move it there. What is the difference between here and cross validated? Im pretty new :D

Comment: Both are stack-exchange fora, but SO is for programming questions, CV is for statistical questions.  Certainly there is some overlap in those topics (statistical programming), but your question is indeed more statistical than about writing syntax.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199677/when-to-post-on-cross-validated-over-stack-overflow

Comment: FYI, the OP posted this on CV:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/593447/constrained-model-demonstrates-slightly-better-fit-than-the-unconstrained-model